# SQL 2016 Mobile Reports Deployment

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, sql-server-2016

Is a new SQL 2016 report web service available to reference in a asp.net site?

If so, does anyone know if the service provides methods for deploying SQL 2016 mobile reports.

Comment: Possible help. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4184/sql-server-2016-reporting-services-mobile-report/

Comment: I looked at this early this year on SQL 2016 CTP 3.3. From what I recall, a web service is available for accessing/deploying mobile reports, but at that time there was no documentation for it (as far as I can tell this is still true). It's a RESTful API passing JSON, and is therefore unlike the SSRS SOAP service.

Comment: Thanks Ed, can't find any information on that API, will post a question to the MSDN forums, thanks!